# Is it possible to render expressions/variables inside a expression/variable?

Tags: python, mako

I am passing few variables to mako template from a python method.

Let say the variables look like this

`var_1 = "mentor_name"`

`var_2 = "mentor_pic_link"`

`var_3 = "<div><p>${var_1} has posted this pic ${var_2}</p></div>"`

The `var_3` comes from mongoDB. So, I want to replace `var_1` and `var_2` inside `var_3` while rendering it in Mako Template.

I tried text replace but it can't be done to more than one variable.

Code looks like this

```py
def send_data_to_mako():
    fragment_context = {
        'var_1': "mentor_name",
        'var_2': "mentor_pic_link",
        'var_3': "<div><p>${var_1} has posted this pic ${var_2}</p></div>",
        }
    fragment.add_content(self.system.render_template('vert_module.html', fragment_context))
```

```
<%page expression_filter="h"/>
<%! from openedx.core.djangolib.markup import HTML %>
<div class="vert-mod">
     ${HTML(var_3)}
</div>
```

Present Output:

> ${var_1} has posted this pic ${var_2}

Expected Output:

> mentor_name has posted this pic mentor_pic_link

Comment: Have you tried regular expressions?

Comment: No, I haven't tried it. Not Sure how to implement regular expressions in this situation. @HaR

Comment: Do you still need an answer for this? Sorry only now I've seen your reply.